# Problem with Google structured data testing tool and microformat hcard

Tags: structured-data, microformats, hcard

Good day.
I’m trying to implement microformat of the organization (hcard) so that both Google and Yandex perceive it without errors. Everything is ok in Yandex, but Google’s structured data validator displays a warning for pricerange field - but it’s already indicated. And it’s even written in the validator ... Here is a screenshot
[image: Google Structured Data Testing Tool Warning]

And here is the code itself:

```html
<div class="vcard">
  <a class="fn org url" href="http://www.commerce.net/">CommerceNet</a>
  <img class="logo-ft photo" src="images/logo-footer.png" alt="Company Logo">
  <div class="adr">
    <span class="type">Work</span>:
    <div class="street-address">169 University Avenue</div>
    <span class="locality">Palo Alto</span>,  
    <abbr class="region" title="California">CA</abbr>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <span class="postal-code">94301</span>
    <div class="country-name">USA</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tel">
   <span class="type">Work</span> +1-650-289-4040
  </div>
   <div>Pricerange: 
   <span class="pricerange">from $10 to $20</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**What could be the problem?** Thanks in advance to everyone who helps.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `org` from `class="fn org url"`, or replace it with any other string and you get your snippet validated. `org`seems to create a kind of conflict.

Comment: Sorry, but this don't work for me...I need that org and fn in code, and they should have the same values. I think this problem cannot be solved and I will refuse this markup and will use another (schema org). Thanks